# Adding a Symbol to a Function

Tags: typescript

Considering the code below

```js
namespace Add {

  type AddType = {
    (x: number, y: number): number;
  };

  const add: AddType = (x: number, y: number) => {
    return x + y;
  };
}
```

Is it possible to add a 'unique symbol' to the AddType, code below.

```js
namespace AddUsingSymbol {

  declare const AddSymbol: unique symbol;

  type AddType = {
    (x: number, y: number): number;
    [AddSymbol]: void;
  };

  /* const add: AddType = (x: number, y: number) => {
    return x + y;
  }; */
  // the code above does not compile
}
```

Is it possible to create an instance of AddType, using the Symbol, in a safe manner without typecasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a type assertion then I'd suggest using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the symbol-keyed property into the function object, like so:

```
const add: AddType = Object.assign((x: number, y: number) => {
    return x + y;
}, { [AddSymbol]: undefined });
```

This will be considered type safe by the compiler.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBAJmgqlAlsA5gMoCeYARgPYA2SA3gLABQTSrSaE8VIATsvBWBQALqgwly1AFxIArsBwBHWciilKVANxMWbYcRjJ0aACoHkAXjq62bABQAPGcFnkIPADRJiz12XcAlL5uPNqMtrYA2sYSGgC6MgBuFDhoYbYAvmE2SAJCoiAYMsZmhkhWAPJkAFacwgB0IFC4+MB2jsH+nt6dgeUAfNbhEax8wrI8wEgOSADU3ulsGV60SNHi6tQJcsAcAGZ4EGhIGQHZzIwZTEA)